# Stop Autolaunched Flow when Object Deleted

Tags: process-builder, visual-workflow, delete

We are using Autolaunched Flows, many of which include Pauses of several days. Because of the Pauses, many Flows are throwing errors because the Objects that triggered them (via Process Builder) get deleted. In most instances these were test objects and were purposefully deleted.

What is the best way in a Flow to detect if an object has been deleted? (Or, even better, is there a way to automatically delete related Flow interviews when an object is deleted?)

Comment: seems as if the flow is passed a recordId, that the Get Records element, if no record retrieved should just stop the flow in an immediately succeeding decision block

Comment: I should have clarified that these Flows include pauses of several days, and that the errors are being thrown when the Flows are resumed (by which point the object has been deleted).